# Getting parameter from user and using it in post method

Tags: php, spring, spring-boot, post, get

```
@RequestMapping(value="/thyroidReport",method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST }, produces = "application/JSON")
   public ArrayList<thyroidMedicalReport> getThyroidDetails(@RequestParam("id") String personId) throws IOException{
      return thyroidReportHandler.getDetails(personId);
   }
```

The above code is to POST the thyroid report details in JSON format. However, i need to pick up the user ID from my website (PHP code) for which is need a GET method too with the request for the ID.

The POST call should be made in the format : 
    http://localhost:8090/thyroidReport?id=123

I am getting the following compilation error:

```
The method getDetails(String) in the type thyroidReportHandler is not applicable for the arguments
```

Comment: why are you mixing POST and GET in one method? Can you provide som more details on the code of 'thyroidReportHandler.getDetails(personId);'?

Comment: My thyroidReportHandler retrieves data from my database and returns that to the call function. I am using post and get because, i want to 'get' the user id from the calling function and then 'post' the corresponding data. @flxplzk

Comment: Could you provide the `ThyroidReportHandler#getDetails` method implementation?

Comment: What confuses me is that you have an endpoint method that both generates new reports and returns them, and can be addressed with GET and POST. Is not the technical correctness to use only GET and if at the query time no report exists to create one?

Answer (score 0):

If your service `thyroidReportHandler` works, you could do it this way:

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/thyroidReport", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ArrayList<thyroidMedicalReport>getThyroidDetails(@RequestParam(value="id") String personId) throws IOException{
      return thyroidReportHandler.getDetails(personId);
   }
```

You don't need to perform two HTTP calls, you can provide all your information in the GET.

By the way, I would make your class `thyroidMedicalReport` start by a uppercase letter!